# Can't add evolutions dependency to Play! project

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-evolutions

Can't add evolutions dependency to Play! project.

Hadn't this problem with another project and with another dependencies

[image]

Comment: Looks like a resolver issue. Where are your resolvers? What have you tried to do to fix it?

Comment: Add more details, especially exact version of Play you are using, also tag it with Play version

Comment: Are you using idea's auto-import feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a tutorial on Play + Slick + MySQL a while ago, just check: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Just recreated app with activator, not with IDE.